# Numpy string array pad with string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, numpy

I have created a 2d Numpy string array like so:

```
a = np.full((2, 3), '#', dtype=np.unicode)
print(a)
```

The output is:

```
array([['#', '#', '#'], ['#', '#', '#']], dtype=`'<U1'`)
```

I would like to pad it with '?' on all sides with a width of 1. I'm expecting output as:

```
array([
['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
['?', '#', '#', '#', '?'],
['?', '#', '#', '#', '?'],
['?', '#', '#', '#', '?'],
['?', '?', '?', '?', '?']],
dtype=`'<U1')
```

I tried the following:

```
b = np.pad(a, ((1, 1), (1, 1)), 'constant', constant_values=(('?', '?'), ('?', '?')))
```

But that gives the following error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/arraypad.py", line 1357, in pad
    cast_to_int=False)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/arraypad.py", line 1069, in _normalize_shape
    return tuple(tuple(axis) for axis in arr.tolist())
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'tolist'
```

Similar code works for integers. What am I doing wrong for strings?

Comment: This is simply a `numpy` bug -- it's implementation detail assumes too specific conditions about the array, and it dumps an unhelpful message when it can't go on. As @Kasramvd has shown, you can circumvent it by creating your own padding function.

Comment: I get a different error in 1.14.  Notice that some of the modes involve maximum and interpolation. The 'constant' mode may be just a special case of one of those.  It's overkill for a simple padding like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pad your array with string literals. Instead as it's mentioned [in documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) you can use a `pad_with` function as follows:

```
In [79]: def pad_with(vector, pad_width, iaxis, kwargs):
    ...:     pad_value = kwargs.get('padder', '?')
    ...:     vector[:pad_width[0]] = pad_value
    ...:     vector[-pad_width[1]:] = pad_value
    ...:     return vector
    ...: 

In [80]: 

In [80]: np.pad(a, 1, pad_with)
Out[80]: 
array([['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
       ['?', '#', '#', '#', '?'],
       ['?', '#', '#', '#', '?'],
       ['?', '#', '#', '#', '?'],
       ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?']], dtype='<U1')
```

Note that in line `pad_value = kwargs.get('padder', '?')` in `pad_with` function you should use a default padding value in case there's no padding argument provided in `np.pad`'s caller. You an pass the intended `padder` as a keyword argument to the function.

```
In [82]: np.pad(a, 1, pad_with, padder='*')
Out[82]: 
array([['*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
       ['*', '#', '#', '#', '*'],
       ['*', '#', '#', '#', '*'],
       ['*', '#', '#', '#', '*'],
       ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*']], dtype='<U1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you can get `pad` to work, it would be faster to insert `a` into a blank `b`.  `pad` is setup for complex padding patterns, and does the job iteratively - row by row, column by column.

```
In [29]: a = np.full((2,3),'#')
In [30]: a
Out[30]: 
array([['#', '#', '#'],
       ['#', '#', '#']], dtype='<U1')
In [31]: b = np.full((4,5),'?')
In [32]: b
Out[32]: 
array([['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
       ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
       ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
       ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?']], dtype='<U1')
In [33]: b[1:-1,1:-1] = a
In [34]: b
Out[34]: 
array([['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
       ['?', '#', '#', '#', '?'],
       ['?', '#', '#', '#', '?'],
       ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?']], dtype='<U1')
```

---

Here's the clever `pad_with` solution, with an added print so we can see how often it is called:

```
In [36]: def pad_with(vector, pad_width, iaxis, kwargs):
    ...:     ...:     print(vector)
    ...:     ...:     pad_value = kwargs.get('padder', '?')
    ...:     ...:     vector[:pad_width[0]] = pad_value
    ...:     ...:     vector[-pad_width[1]:] = pad_value
    ...:     ...:     return vector
    ...: 
In [37]: np.pad(a,1,pad_with)
['' '' '' '']
['' '#' '#' '']
['' '#' '#' '']
['' '#' '#' '']
['' '' '' '']
['?' '?' '?' '?' '?']
['' '#' '#' '#' '']
['' '#' '#' '#' '']
['?' '?' '?' '?' '?']
Out[37]: 
array([['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
       ['?', '#', '#', '#', '?'],
       ['?', '#', '#', '#', '?'],
       ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?']], dtype='<U1')
```